# Referenced form errors

Tags: xcode

I was using xcode 4 and now I've upgraded it to xcode 5. Now when I try to product -> archive my project I get those errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectMapping", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RestObjectMappings.o
  "_RKMIMETypeJSON", referenced from:
      ___54-[RestObjectManager sendRestObject:method:usingBlock:]_block_invoke in RestObjectManager.o
      ___67-[RestObjectManager sendRestObject:method:resourcePath:usingBlock:]_block_invoke in RestObjectManager.o
      ___73-[RestObjectManager  sendRestObject:method:withResponseAsList:usingBlock:]_block_invoke in RestObjectManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HttpNetworkObserver.o
      objc-class-ref in RestObjectManager.o
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController1.o
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController2.o
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController3.o
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController4.o
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController5.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HttpManager.o
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController1.o
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController2.o
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController3.o
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController4.o
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController5.o
  "_RKReachabilityDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
      +[HttpNetworkObserver registerNetworkObserver] in HttpNetworkObserver.o
      +[HttpNetworkObserver unregisterNetworkObserver] in HttpNetworkObserver.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKJSONParserJSONKit", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController1.o
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController2.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKURL", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RestObjectManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How to get rid of those errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `arm64` from `Build Settings`